# Kafka Errors after version upgrade from 0.10.2.2 to 2.1.1 "due to Corrupt time index found, time index file"

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having a 3 node kafka and 3 node zookeeper cluster. Each kafka and zookeeper pair is running on same VM. I have upgraded kafka version from 0.10.2.2 to 2.1.1 After one day it starts giving below Warning messages for all topics. Kafka upgrade was done in rolling manner.
All kafka topics are having Replication Factor 2 and min.ISR 2. Can someone help get the actual root cause of the issue.

```
[2019-03-28 17:23:55.877+0000] WARN [Log partition=FirstTopic-6, dir=/apps/kafka/data] Found a corrupted index file corresponding to log file /apps/kafka/data/FirstTopic-6/00000000000000000494.log due to Corrupt time index found, time index file (/apps/kafka/data/FirstTopic-6/00000000000000000494.timeindex) has non-zero size but the last timestamp is 0 which is less than the first timestamp 1553720469480}, recovering segment and rebuilding index files... (kafka.log.Log)

[2019-03-28 17:23:55.877+0000] WARN [Log partition=NewTopic-3, dir=/apps/kafka/data] Found a corrupted index file corresponding to log file /apps/kafka/data/NewTopic-3/00000000000000000494.log due to Corrupt time index found, time index file (/apps/kafka/data/NewTopic-3/00000000000000000494.timeindex) has non-zero size but the last timestamp is 0 which is less than the first timestamp 1553720469480}, recovering segment and rebuilding index files... (kafka.log.Log)

[2019-03-28 17:23:55.877+0000] WARN [Log partition=SecondTopic-3, dir=/apps/kafka/data] Found a corrupted index file corresponding to log file /apps/kafka/data/SecondTopic-3/00000000000000000494.log due to Corrupt time index found, time index file (/apps/kafka/data/SecondTopic-3/00000000000000000494.timeindex) has non-zero size but the last timestamp is 0 which is less than the first timestamp 1553720469480}, recovering segment and rebuilding index files... (kafka.log.Log)
```

Comment: Is this really an error and something to worry about? The level is WARN and the message suggests it has been dealt with. Have you noticed any other issues with how your cluster is operating?

Comment: Hi Mark,

Its not a blocker for me but sometimes kafka behaves weirdly . I'm not sure it is the culprit but wanted to know the actual root cause of the problem.